# Is there a way to view chat transcripts only of a chat room?

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

If I want to see only the chat transcripts of a specific chat room, is there a way to do so? As of now, when I want to see previous chats when I was not present, I enter the room, the room is loaded and I scroll up to see them. So is there not a way to do so without entering the room? Like we seen the transcripts when somebody @ us and we can see the transcripts by not entering the room from the notifications.

Actually sometimes, internet becomes slow if I am in rural areas and the chat room does not load easily. In that case, viewing transcripts would be easier IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To view the chat transcript of a room, grab its ID from the URL and replace it here:

```
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/{chat-room-id}
```

For Stack Overflow chat:

```
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/{chat-room-id}
```

For Meta Stack Overflow chat:

```
https://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/{chat-room-id}
```

When you view the list of rooms, the link to the transcript will be at the bottom right of said room thumbnail.

> [image: shot of a chat room]